# Does kendo.mobile.min.js do template edit functions?

Tags: kendo-ui

Struggling to determine which kendo UI widgets/functions work with kendomobile :(

Has anyone gotten this example to work with mobile, specifically the editTemplate segment?

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html

My current code looks like this

```
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script>
                var eventDetail =  $("#eventDetail").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#eventDetail-template").html()),
                editTemplate: kendo.template($("#update_eventDetail-template").html())
            }).delegate(".k-edit-button", "click", function(e) {
                eventDetail.edit($(this).closest(".fields"));
                e.preventDefault();
            }).delegate(".k-delete-button", "click", function(e) {
                eventDetail.remove($(this).closest(".product-view"));
                e.preventDefault();
            }).delegate(".k-update-button", "click", function(e) {
                eventDetail.save();
                e.preventDefault();
            }).delegate(".k-cancel-button", "click", function(e) {
                eventDetail.cancel();
                e.preventDefault();
            }).data("kendoMobileListView");


            $("#eventDetail").kendoMobileListView({

                pageable: true,
                selectable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                editable: true

            });
</script>
```

Then in the view i have

```
    <input type="button" class="k-edit-button" id="eventEditButton" style="width:30%" data-role="button" data-min="true" value="Edit" />
```

But console throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'edit'
```

Am i right to assume kendo.mobile.min.js doesnt have edit?

Comment: Is there a bot down voting questions? Or was there something wrong with my approach? If you down vote for no reason with no comment then you are not using this tool properly.. At the very least leave a comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Struggling to determine which kendo UI widgets/functions work with kendomobile*

All framework features such as templates, MVVM, DataSource, Validator, etc. works with KendoUI Mobile.

*Am i right to assume kendo.mobile.min.js doesnt have edit?*

Yes, Mobile ListView does not have a build-in editing functionality like Web ListView (those are two different widgets). If you would like to edit the data in a Mobile ListView please consider using MVVM and DataSource's API methods. From [here](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mobile/listview/listview---mvvm-crud-operations.aspx) you can download a sample project that demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Oddly your answer is confusing as ALL framework features dont work with mobile.. such as  built in editing..

Comment: I assume that you refer to the editing functionality of the Grid/Web ListView. In my option, this is feature of particular widget.

Comment: Well, there are ALOT more functions found in the kendo ui js than found in the kendo mobile js, including the 2 you mention here..